# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory error with SOAPUI selenium script

Tags: selenium, groovy, soapui

I am trying to run this code from groovy script but getting the error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory error

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

//Initiate WebDriver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe");
log.info(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver()


//Setup Environment
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

//Your Code
Thread.sleep(10000)
driver.quit()
```

This is what I have tried:

1) I have placed the selenium jar 3.0.1 placed in the lib and bin folder of soap folder. 
2) I have tried downgrading my selenium to 2.3.9
3) I have tried with all three browsers(i.e, firefox and chrome)
4) Tried adding the driver in the path

Comment: Please check if this is helpful? https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/58

Comment: i do not seem to understand that :(